# java, apache poi, nullpoint error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I have an excel file that look looks like this

```
Name       Mark
CHE102     80
MTE100     85
MATH115 
.
.
.
.
.
..
```

I am using this code this method to extract the information

```
public void readData(Row row,Sheet ws){
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
    name=cell.getStringCellValue();
    cell=cellIterator.next();
    mark=cell.getNumericCellValue();
}
```

In my main im using the for loop as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            arr[i]=new Test();
            Row row=rowIterator.next();
            arr[i].readData(row,ws);
             arr[i].setGrade();
             arr[i].outputData();
        }
```

but the problem is that since I have many empty cells in my excel file im getting a nullpoint error
how do i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that problem is in "Mark" column - where the cell is empty then `cell.getNumericCellValue` throws error: try to use `try ... catch`

Something like this:

```
try {
   mark = cell.getNumericCellValue();
} catch (Exception exc) {
   mark = null;
}
```

Moreover, If the row count is not known beforehand, you should write iterator termination logic, in the example you're just looping till 5.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly.
sorry but im a noob in progamming, what is iterator termination logic

Comment: I mean "Termination logic": Somehow you had predicted that the row count always will be 5 (`for(int i=0;i<5;i++)`). It's okay if it is like that, but in many situations you don't know the exact number of rows - in that case you should somehow terminate the loop. For example you can check like that: if "Name" cell value is null then exit.

Answer (score 1):

You should guard against nullvalues by explicitly checking for them:

for example you could write

```
name= (cell==null) ? "" : cell.getStringCellValue();
```

However, the cellIterator only returns the non-blank cells, so you would get weird results when the 'name' is empty.

Instead try:

```
public void readData(Row row,Sheet ws){
    Cell cell=row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    name= (cell==null) ? "" : cell.getStringCellValue();
    cell=row.getCell(1, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    mark= (cell==null) ? 0 : cell.getNumericCellValue();
}
```

To explicitly process both cells. Of course, you can use a different logic rather than using the empty string and 0 for non-existant cells.

see also: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Change it as per your requirement.

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(myRowNum);
int lastColumn = r.getLastCellNum();

for (int cn=0; cn<lastColumn; cn++) {
   Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
   if (c == null) {
      // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
   } else {
      // Do something useful with the cell's contents
   }
}
```